# Integrate over all orthonormal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, differential-geometry, lie-groups, orthogonal-matrices

Consider the following integration
$$\int_\phi R dR $$
where $\phi$ is a set of all orthonormal matrices.
In case the above integration doesn't make sense, what I want to evaluate is the following:

$$\frac{1}{|\phi|} \sum_{R\in \phi } R $$

My guess is that the answer is a matrix of 0s, but I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: I think integration makes sense. The set of orthogonal matrices is a group and there is unique "rotation" invariant measure on it (Haar's measure).

Comment: The negative of every *orthogonal* matrix is again orthogonal. Sum in pairs.

Comment: @TedShifrin nice haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem does make sense, but to make sense of it you need to have a measure on the space of orthogonal matrices.  The standard choice if you want to integrate over a compact Lie group is to take $\mu$ to be the left (or right) invariant Haar measure such that the total group has measure 1.  So $\mu(S)=\mu(gS)$ for every measureable set $S$ and $g\in G$.  If you have a Haar measure and a measurable function $f$, then translation invariance of the measure implies that

$$\int_G f(x)d\mu(x)=\int_G f(g^{-1}x) d\mu(x)$$

for any $g\in G$.  Now, if $\rho$ is a representation of $G$, so that we are integrating matrices (which we can view as coordinatewise integration), we can use this translation invariance.

$$\int_G \rho(x)d\mu(x)=\int_G \rho(g^{-1}x)d\mu(x)=\int_G \rho(g)^{-1}\rho(x)d\mu(x)=\rho(g)^{-1}\int_G \rho(x)d\mu(x).$$

So the integral, whatever it is, will also be preserved by multiplication with anything in the image of $\rho$.

Taking $G=O(n)$, $\rho$ the standard representation on $\mathbb R^n$, and $g=-I$ is enough to see the integral must be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Show that the value of the integral is invariant under rotations.